# Showing a comma seperated list of Database ID's in that order PHP/MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

I have a database with 2 tables that looks like this:

**CATEGORIES**

```
Name        |    Items
---------------------------------
At Home     |    3,4,8,9
At Office   |    10,3,2,1
```

---

**ITEMS**

```
Name        |    id
--------------------------------
Fix Car     |    3
Mow Lawn    |    4
Garbage     |    8
Laundry     |    9
Desk Clean  |    10
```

---

In the Categories Table the comma separated numbers represent a list of Items by id.

How would I do a SQL Select that selects all of the items in a specific category (e.g. "At Home") and then orders them in the same order as the Items Column.

The Database has been simplified to hopefully make the question easier to understand.

Also if you can think of a better way to organize the Database for this type of application that would be good to know.

**Customized Order Is Critical For This Project**

Comment: No. Please doesn't does this. Normalizez your table.

Comment: Start by reading: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization   for "better organization"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If possible, create a 3rd table to **normalize** your DB, or look at edit below :-)

```
CATEGORIES

Name        |    id
---------------------------------
At Home     |    1
At Office   |    2


ITEMS

Name        |    id
--------------------------------
Fix Car     |    3
Mow Lawn    |    4
Garbage     |    8
Laundry     |    9
Desk Clean  |    10


LINKS

cat_id     |   item_id
--------------------------------
1          |   3
1          |   4
1          |   8
1          |   9
2          |   10
2 etc.
```

Then go:

```
SELECT items.name 
FROM items 
LEFT JOIN links ON items.id = links.item_id
WHERE items.cat_id = 1
ORDER BY items.id
```

I just realized I operated on the assumption that every `items` can be in multiple `categories`. If you want 1 item --> 1 category, there's no need for a third table, just add a field to `items`, and another one for custom-ordering:

ITEMS

```
Name        |    id   | cat_id |  order
-----------------------------------------
Fix Car     |    3    |   1    |   1
Mow Lawn    |    4    |   2    |   1
Kill Cat    |    9    |   1    |   2

SELECT name 
FROM items 
WHERE cat_id = 1
ORDER BY order
```

Comment: The only problem I forsee with this is that there is no way to custom order the items in each category.

Comment: @Talon: insert a field `order (int)`

Comment: Each item can be in multiple categories so it would have to be a third table. that's a good idea

Answer (score 0):

use `FIND_IN_SET`

```
SELECT  a.name, b.Name itemName
FROM    categories a
        INNER JOIN items b
            ON FIND_IN_SET(b.id, a.items) > 0
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/77025/3)

Better normalize the table for better performance. One disadvantage of this is that it is hard to achieve your requirements, eg. *..order them in the same order as the Items Column*

Comment: Yeah any ideas how to order it based on the custom order? That's super critical.

Comment: Normalise the data - that is super critical.